# Consistency of the pointer to a slice element

Tags: go

Consider the simple code sample:

```
s := make([]int, 0, 10<<20) // Create a slice with 10M int items
s = append(s, 123456789)    // Append any random number
p := &s[0]                  // Pointer to a 1st element of the slice

// Adding new items. Slice expected to be re-allocated in the memory.
for i := 0; i < 100<<20; i++ {
    s = append(s, i)
}
```

So, the question is: In case of slice "s" was re-allocated after append(), will pointer "p" also point to a new address of the 1st element of the slice "s" ? I.e. "p" always hold an address to the value "123456789". Or pointer need to be re-created?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would the value of `p` be altered by appending to `s`? The address stored in `p` is not going to be changed unless you modify `p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointer `p` will always point to the first element of `s` that was returned from the first append. Consecutive appends will create new arrays and copy the contents of the slice to those arrays, but `p` will continue to point to the first element of the same array. The arrays allocated during the intermediate appends will be garbage collected, but the last one assigned to `s`, and the first one pointed to by `p` will not be as long as `s` and `p` are kept alive, because there are active references to them.